# Problem with fetching value out of foreach loop in php

Tags: php, foreach

I am having trouble fetching values from foreach loop. I always get NULL values when I try to send request in postman. Here is my code and what I have tried.

php code

```
$symbol = $request->symbol;
$ticker = $api->prices();

foreach ($symbol as $ticker => $pairname)
{
    echo $pairname;
}
```

in postman I send request like this

```
{
   "symbol":"BTCUSDT"
}
```

When I var_dump $ticker variable the response I get is as follows

```
array(147) {
["XRPBUSD"]=>
string(6) "0.5881"
["MKRUSDT"]=>
string(7) "2003.70"
["SRMUSDT"]=>
string(6) "2.2300"
["BTCUSDT"]=>
string(6) "37173.34" ... } and etc.
```

I need when I send symbol value in postman that it prints that value in foreach loop from that $ticker variable. Currently I get NULL value.

Comment: With your current code, you are not looping over the contents of `$ticker` - you are looping over the contents of `$symbol`, and you _overwrite_ the original content that `$ticker` had before the loop, with the loop index.

Comment: @CBroe Can you tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Why, do you not know how a foreach loop actually works? In that case, you should go read up on it, rather than have us give you private tutoring on such absolute basics.

Comment: (If you just want to show the value that corresponds to the key you send, then this should rather not use a loop to begin with. You can just check if an entry under that key exists using `isset`, and if so, you output it directly.)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a string and not a json array, it is normal that the foreach does not read.

Try this :

```
"symbol": [
{
  "BTCUSDT"
}]
```